# No syntax highlighting with React Monaco Editor

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

Just installed [React Monaco Editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-monaco-editor) and seems to be functioning properly except there is no syntax highlighting. I'm trying to use "python" as the language but the font stays the same gray default colour:

[image]

Any ideas on how to correct the issue?

Here is my Code.js where I'm running the Monaco Editor:

```
import React from "react";
import MonacoEditor from "react-monaco-editor";

class Code extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      code: 'print("Hello, World!")'
    };
  }
  editorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    console.log("editorDidMount", editor);
    editor.focus();
  }
  onChange(newValue, e) {
    console.log("onChange", newValue, e);
  }
  render() {
    const code = this.state.code;
    const options = {
      selectOnLineNumbers: true,
      fontSize: 18,
      colorDecorators: true
    };
    return (
      <MonacoEditor
        width="800"
        height="600"
        language="python"
        theme="vs-dark"
        value={code}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Code;
```

Also I added this code to the top of webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
      // available options are documented at https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin#options
      languages: ['python']
    })
  ]
};

const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const MONACO_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/monaco-editor');

module.exports = {
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: APP_DIR,
  use: [{
    loader: 'style-loader',
  }, {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
      namedExport: true,
    },
  }],
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: MONACO_DIR,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you fail to configure CSS for Monaco Editor in Webpack? Perhaps that's issue since everything else looks good.

```js
const path = require('path');
const MONACO_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/monaco-editor');

{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: MONACO_DIR,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}
```

### Solution

The Problem was nothing with the configuration but the place where it was configured.
To customize webpack in your React CRA boilerplate, you must **eject the app** or use **customize-cra** if you don't want to eject, and do the configuration. OP here configured webpack inside `node-modules/`, That's not the right to configure your webpack, like at all. Use `react-app-rewired` with `customize-cra`.

Comment: Tried adding that in but didn't seem to have any effect. No errors either. I updated the webpack code above with exactly what I inserted to the top of the file. Have I inserted something incorrectly?

Comment: @StackUnderFlow which boiler plate are you using? Are you sure the webpack is working?

Comment: Using Create React App and editing the webpack.config file from this path: /node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js

Comment: That's not the right to configure your webpack, like at all. Use react-app-rewired with customize-cra.

Comment: That makes perfects sense now and works with rewired + cra. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the Monaco editor with `create-react-app` you will need a different approach, if you don't want to eject the app (to allow manually editing the webpack config file). [This paragraph](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor#usage-with-create-react-app) describes it pretty well:

> The easiest way to use the react-monaco-editor with create-react-app is to use the react-app-rewired project. For setting it up, the following steps are required:
>
> - Install react-app-rewired: npm install -D react-app-rewired
> - Replace react-scripts by react-app-rewired in the scripts section of your packages.json
> - Create a config-overrides.js in the root directory of your project with the following content:
>
> ```js
> const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
>
> module.exports = function override(config, env) {  
>     config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
>         languages: ['json']
>     }));
>     return config;
> }
> ```
>
> For more information checkout the documentation of react-app-rewired
> [here](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).

I did not have to specify anything else to make it work. No need to specify loaders for webpack manually.

Answer (score 3):

For me both of the above answers are not working - not sure if it's related to Codesandbox or I did a mistake.

But using [@monaco-editor/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react) is working with-out any changes to the CRA setup.

The only difference in the usage is that the default export is not a controlled component - so `onchange` is not working.

To have a controlled component, just use `import {ControlledEditor as MonacoEditor} from "@monaco-editor/react"`. The `onchange` handler needs to be slightly modified, first the event & then the `newText` - just a small difference in the implementation.

The usage looks like following:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ControlledEditor as MonacoEditor } from "@monaco-editor/react";
export const Editor = () => {
  const [code, setCode] = useState(`const greeting = () => {
    alert("Hello world");
}`);

  const options = {
    minimap: {
      enabled: false
    }
  };

  const changeHandler = (evt, newText) => {
    setCode(newText);
  };

  const editorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    console.log("editorDidMount", editor);
  };

  return (
    <MonacoEditor
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      language="javascript"
      theme="vs-dark"
      value={code}
      options={options}
      onChange={changeHandler}
      editorDidMount={editorDidMount}
    />
  );
};
```

The `options` can be used to modify the Monaco editor. In my case I don't want to display the minimap. All available options can be found in the [editor api docs](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#editoroptions)

You can find the working demo in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editor-controlled-component-rs1vk?file=/src/components/Editor.jsx:0-718).

The only thing that I found that is not working is undo/redo as described in the following [issue](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react/issues/51). No change event triggered but I'll check this later - for now I'm happy with it.

Comment: Using `@monaco-editor/react` works partially for me -  I get no highlights.